# Cannot get the modal pop up value in controller using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I could not get text field value present inside the modal pop up using Angular.js. I am providing my code below.

view.html:

```
<modal title="Driver Information" visible="showModal">
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3" ng-model="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="singlebutton" ng-click="save();">Save</button>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</modal>
```

My controller page is given below.

viewcontroller.js:

```
var dashboard=angular.module('easyride');
dashboard.controller('viewcontroller',function($scope){
    $scope.save=function(){
       console.log('comment',$scope.comment);
    }
})
dashboard.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

In the console message I am getting the `blank` value even I am entering some value in comment field and click on save button. Here I need to get the user typed the comment value after click on save button and once the value will be printed via console message the pop up should close.

Comment: Have you tried removing `scope:false` and check if it works that way?

Comment: Here I have `scope:true`.

Comment: Yes I see, and that is why `$scope.comment` exists in the directive scope, but it is not the same as `$scope.comment` of the controller's scope. Use dot in your model or bindings to pass the callback into your directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made some simple changes in your code, check it and it works

```
visible="showModal"
ng-click="save(comment);"


$scope.save=function(comment){
        console.log('comment',comment);
        $scope.comment = comment;
        $scope.showModal = false;
    }
```

here is jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0m8mpx43/2/

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it from the ng-click itself

```
<modal title="Driver Information" visible="showModal">
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3" ng-model="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="singlebutton" ng-click="save(comment);">Save</button>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</modal>
```

then in controller

```
var dashboard=angular.module('easyride');
dashboard.controller('viewcontroller',function($scope){
    $scope.save=function(comment){
       console.log('comment',comment);
    }
})
```

Comment: Let me to try and let you know ? How to close is popup inside that click event.

Comment: try $(element).modal('toggle');

Comment: what is `element` inside the controller.

Comment: it is the element on which the directive is used on

Comment: so in this case its the modal tag

Comment: I did as per you but see this error `angularjslatest.js:123 ReferenceError: element is not defined`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165121/discussion-between-satya-and-hussain-mohd).

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in my comment - you are creating a new scope by inheriting parent scope, so `$scope.comment` in your controller will not be the same as `$scope.comment` in your directive. You have to use a "dot in your model" to make it work. If you want to close a modal after - you can implement this method inside the directive and then call it by passing as an argument. Here is a working example, that illustrates the mentioned changes to your code:

```js
angular.module('easyride', [])
.controller('viewcontroller',function($scope){
    $scope.modelForModal = {
      showModal: true,
      comment: '',
      save: function (closeModal){
        console.log('comment',$scope.modelForModal.comment);
        if (angular.isFunction(closeModal)) { closeModal(); }
      }
    };
})
.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });
        
        scope.$parent.closeModal = scope.closeModal = function() {
          $(element).modal('hide');
        };

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body ng-app="easyride">

<div ng-controller="viewcontroller">

<modal title="Driver Information" visible="modelForModal.showModal">
   <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3" ng-model="modelForModal.comment"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="singlebutton" ng-click="modelForModal.save(closeModal);">Save</button>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</modal>
   
</div>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```